# YoutubeApi loader doesn't disppear

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Since the last youtube version (11.01.56), with the Youtube API 1.2.2, when I start a video, the loader icon doesn't disappear when the video is playing. With a older version, and the same code, the loader disappeared when the video is started and is showed only when video is buffering (10.18.55).

I search for API to disable it on the last version, but I found anything...

Can you help me to solve my problem or fix it for the next youtube release?

More detail: I use the YouTubePlayer with com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.